# Apply facet_wrap from ggplot to certain values from column

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I wrote a code:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~drv)
```

Here is the output:
[image]

As you see, here are three facets, because there are three type of values in column "dev". Now, I want to get the same graph, but only with types "f" and "r". So it must look exactly like one above, but without first facet "4". How could i do that? I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~drv==c("f", "r"))
```

Here is the output of it, which is totally not what i want:

[image]

Comment: Filter the values that you want. ? `mpg %>% filter(drv %in% c("f", "r")) %>% ggplot() + aes(displ, hwy) +  geom_point() + facet_wrap(~drv)`

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to filter or subset your data first. You can do it before plotting and assign the filtered data to a new object, you can do it from within the call to `ggplot()`, or you can use the pipe operator from `dplyr`.

**Subsetting**

```
# saving as a new object
mpg_subset <- mpg[which(mpg$drv %in% c("r", "f")),]

# within ggplot
ggplot(data = mpg[which(mpg$drv %in% c("r", "f")),],
       aes(displ, hwy) + ...

# using a pipe
Library(dplyr)
mpg[which(mpg$drv %in% c("r", "f")),] %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy) + ...
```

**Filtering with dplyr**

```
 # saving as a new object
Library(dplyr)
mpg_subset <- filter(mpg, drv %in% c("r", "f"))

# within ggplot
Library(dplyr)
ggplot(data = filter(mpg, drv %in% c("r", "f")),
       aes(displ, hwy) + ...

# using a pipe
Library(dplyr)
mpg %>%
  filter(drv %in% c("r", "f")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(displ, hwy) + ...

# using a pipe in ggplot call
Library(dplyr)
ggplot(data =  mpg %>% filter(drv %in% c("r", "f")),
       aes(displ, hwy) + ...
```